# (ASK) Temporary Fingerprint Scanner Save File

Tags: java, fingerprint

i have a problem with my project to pass the graduation..
i try to make a attendance fingerprint system..

my problem is when i scan my fingerprint and save my fingerprint template.. and then i close my netbeans...
the save file is not save, being deleted... and i must scan my fingerprint again if i want to verification them..

anyone can help my problem..

thanks...

+++ here the code +++

```
import java.io.*;
import java.beans.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import com.digitalpersona.onetouch.*;

public class MainForm extends JFrame
{
public static String TEMPLATE_PROPERTY = "template";
private DPFPTemplate template;
    private String file;
public class TemplateFileFilter extends javax.swing.filechooser.FileFilter {
    @Override public boolean accept(File f) {
        return f.getName().endsWith(".fpt");
    }
    @Override public String getDescription() {
        return "Fingerprint Template File (*.fpt)";
    }
}
MainForm() {
    setState(Frame.NORMAL);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    this.setTitle("Verifikasi dan Pendaftaran Sidik Jari");
    setResizable(false);

    final JButton enroll = new JButton("Pendaftaran Sidik Jari");
    enroll.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) { onEnroll(); }});

    final JButton verify = new JButton("Verifikasi Sidik Jari");
    verify.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) { onVerify(); }});

    final JButton save = new JButton("Simpan");
    save.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) { onSave(); }});

    final JButton load = new JButton("Baca Template");
    load.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) { onLoad(); }});

    final JButton quit = new JButton("Tutup");
    quit.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) { System.exit(0); }});

    this.addPropertyChangeListener(TEMPLATE_PROPERTY, new PropertyChangeListener() {
        public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
            verify.setEnabled(template != null);
            save.setEnabled(template != null);
            if (evt.getNewValue() == evt.getOldValue()) return;
            if (template != null)

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(MainForm.this, "Template sidik jari siap untuk verifikasi sidik jari.", "Pendaftaran Sidik Jari", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                                    onSave();


        }
    });

    JPanel center = new JPanel();
    center.setLayout(new GridLayout(4, 1, 0, 5));
    center.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(20, 20, 5, 20));
    center.add(enroll);
    center.add(verify);
    center.add(save);
    center.add(load);

    JPanel bottom = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.TRAILING));
    bottom.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5, 20, 5, 20));
    bottom.add(quit);

    setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    add(center, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    add(bottom, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);

    pack();
    setSize((int)(getSize().width*1.6), getSize().height);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setTemplate(null);
    setVisible(true);
}

private void onEnroll() {
    EnrollmentForm form = new EnrollmentForm(this);
    form.setVisible(true);
}

private void onVerify() {
    VerificationForm form = new VerificationForm(this);
    form.setVisible(true);
}

private void onSave() {
    JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
    chooser.addChoosableFileFilter(new TemplateFileFilter());
    while (true) {
        if (chooser.showSaveDialog(this) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
            try {
                File file = chooser.getSelectedFile();
                                    //file="xxx";
                if (!file.toString().toLowerCase().endsWith(".fpt"))
                    file = new File(file.toString() + ".fpt");
                                           // file=file.toString()+".fpt";
                if (file.exists()) {
                    int choice = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(this,
                        String.format("File \"%1$s\" sudah ada.\nApakah mau mengganti?", file.toString()),
                        "Penyimpanan Sidik Jari",
                        JOptionPane.YES_NO_CANCEL_OPTION);
                    if (choice == JOptionPane.NO_OPTION)
                        continue;
                    else if (choice == JOptionPane.CANCEL_OPTION)
                        break;
                                }
                FileOutputStream stream = new FileOutputStream(file);
                stream.write(getTemplate().serialize());
                stream.close();
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, ex.getLocalizedMessage(), "Penyimpanan Sidik Jari", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            }
        }
        break;
    }
}

private void onLoad() {
    JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
    chooser.addChoosableFileFilter(new TemplateFileFilter());
    if(chooser.showOpenDialog(this) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
        try {
            FileInputStream stream = new FileInputStream(chooser.getSelectedFile());
            byte[] data = new byte[stream.available()];
            stream.read(data);
            stream.close();
            DPFPTemplate t = DPFPGlobal.getTemplateFactory().createTemplate();
            t.deserialize(data);
            setTemplate(t);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, ex.getLocalizedMessage(), "Loading Proses ", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }
    }
}

public DPFPTemplate getTemplate() {
    return template;
}
public void setTemplate(DPFPTemplate template) {
    DPFPTemplate old = this.template;
    this.template = template;
    firePropertyChange(TEMPLATE_PROPERTY, old, template);
}

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new MainForm();
        }
    });
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

In the onSave method you try to get the filename with:

```
file.toString()
```

you should do:

```
file.getName()
```

<strike>`toString()` returns the object as string.</strike>

*** edited ***
for File, toString returns the path of the file, the original code was correct in this.

To make sure the byte are writen to the file you should use:

```
file.flush()
```

Or use an ObjectOutputStream. Its write(byte[]) blocks until the bytes are actualy writen

```
FileOutputStream stream = new FileOutputStream(file);
ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(stream);
out.writeObject(getTemplate().serialize());
out.flush();
out.close();
stream.close();
```

Comment: I has try it but it cant change..
still same..

if i close my netbeans..
i must to save my fingerprint template if i want to verify my save fingerprint

Comment: Exists the file in the disk?

Comment: No the file fingerprint template is doesnt exist in the disk